# temporarily disable orbit around selection

Tags: selection-tools

In the preferences I have "Orbit Around Selection" ticked on and I´d like to keep it that way. But sometimes I´d like to disable it during work just for a few seconds to freely move the view around while still having a specific object selected -- I´d like to turn OAS on and off without going into the prefs, like I can do with the snapping tool by pressing CTRL. Is there any way? Thanks1000!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the same but an alternative instead of "Orbit Around Selection" is to set a keymap to :

[image]

which you can also do manually in the View panel:

[image]